# What exactly does the call to the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method into the main class that perform a Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingutilities, java-threads

I am pretty new in **Swing** and I have the following doubt about this main class that start a Swing application founded on an tutorial project:

```
package com.caveofprogramming.designpatterns.demo1;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.caveofprogramming.designpatterns.demo1.controller.Controller;
import com.caveofprogramming.designpatterns.demo1.model.Model;
import com.caveofprogramming.designpatterns.demo1.view.View;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runApp();
            }

        });
    }

    public static void runApp() {
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View(model);

        Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);
    }

}
```

So this class contains the **main()** method that is the method performed when the application start.

It perform **SwingUtilities.invokeLater()** method that create a **Runnable** object that contains the **run()** method that itself perform the **runApp()** method that is the entrypoint of my Swing application.

My doubt are related about what exactly does the **SwingUtilities.invokeLater()** method. What exactly does? and what is the **Runnable** object that is created as parameter of the **invokeLater()** method? It seems to me that it is an object that automatically implement the **Runnable** interface but I am not sure about it and it is not clear for me why have I to do it.

Can you help me to understand how exactly works the architecture of this simple Swing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really two questions rolled into one.

1. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` makes sure that whatever you want to do happens on the Event Dispatcher Thread. [Since Swing is strictly single threaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), this is required for everything that interacts with Swing and doesn't already run in the EDT (e.g. is called as a result of an event handler) The `main()` method of your application is one such example, as it's invoked by the VM on startup in its own separate thread (called, unsurprisingly, the Main Thread).
2. This is an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). It's a shortcut for creating a class that implements `Runnable` and creating an instance of that class straight away. (Note that it isn't **completely** equivalent with doing that, there are small but important details in which it is different.) `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` will then put this `Runnable` object in the Swing event queue, which will be processed by the EDT (usually a couple of moments) later, calling the `run()` method you provided.

Comment: mmm ok but what exactly uis Event Dispatcher Thread ? Is it a thread used by Swing? What it does? I see the link that you post to me and it say "where all event-handling code is executed. Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also execute on this thread." but what exactly means?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Just click through the entire tutorial, it will be explained in great detail, better than I could.